# Infinite horizontal scroll on background-image with CSS

Tags: css, animation, scroll, infinite

I designed some clouds and now I need to create an infinite CSS horizontal scroll animation (left to right) on them. I tried some solutions but I never found the result I was looking for. Each time there is some breaks in the animation. I really need an infinite effect, non-stop scrolling.

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mwqc00x/)

```
<div class="magic-clds blue-cld"></div>
```

Comment: The first and last semicircles in the cloud do not form a continuous cloud when chained like that. If you can make them both quarter circles, they might give that illusion.

Comment: Yes they form a continuous shape, try to enlarge the jsfiddle Result window please.

Comment: They look a bit off, but what do you mean by breaks in the animation then?

Comment: I mean the animation stop and start again. I want the animation never stop, like real clouds.